# How to add a list in front of current list in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I need to add a list of names in front of a current list of number in sublime and having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

Basically if I have list 1

```
Tom
Jerry
Mary
Sue
```

and

```
12
34
45
39
```

I need the final text file to read

```
12 Tom
34 Jerry
45 Mary
39 Sue
```

I would do it by hand, but its around 800 entries each with about 25 sets of numbers after it.

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer to your primary question in relation to the example you provided. However, the `800 entries each with about 25 sets` scenario seems like it might require different steps.  Feel free to `@tag` me if you update the question's example to show the data as it exists in your actual usage case.

Answer (score 3):

- select `list 1`
- press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + L</kbd> to split the selection into lines
- `cut` the selected lines
- select `list 2`
- press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + L</kbd> to split the selection into lines
- press <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of each line & add a `space` character
- `paste` the previously copied text

**Note:**
This only works if both selections have the same number of lines.